# Filter Hook on plugin update

Tags: plugins, filters, hooks, updates

Is there a WordPress hook I can use to run a function anytime any plugin is updated?

I am trying to write to a log file with the logged in users IP every time something is updated so I can track activity.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe [`upgrader_process_complete()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_process_complete/) action hook.

> Fires when the bulk upgrader process is complete.

[On line 761 of *wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php*](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php#L761)

From source:

> ```
> /**
>  * Fires when the upgrader process is complete.
>  *
>  * See also {@see 'upgrader_package_options'}.
>  *
>  * @since 3.6.0
>  * @since 3.7.0 Added to WP_Upgrader::run().
>  * @since 4.6.0 `$translations` was added as a possible argument to `$hook_extra`.
>  *
>  * @param WP_Upgrader $this WP_Upgrader instance. In other contexts, $this, might be a
>  *                          Theme_Upgrader, Plugin_Upgrader, Core_Upgrade, or Language_Pack_Upgrader instance.
>  * @param array       $hook_extra {
>  *     Array of bulk item update data.
>  *
>  *     @type string $action       Type of action. Default 'update'.
>  *     @type string $type         Type of update process. Accepts 'plugin', 'theme', 'translation', or 'core'.
>  *     @type bool   $bulk         Whether the update process is a bulk update. Default true.
>  *     @type array  $plugins      Array of the basename paths of the plugins' main files.
>  *     @type array  $themes       The theme slugs.
>  *     @type array  $translations {
>  *         Array of translations update data.
>  *
>  *         @type string $language The locale the translation is for.
>  *         @type string $type     Type of translation. Accepts 'plugin', 'theme', or 'core'.
>  *         @type string $slug     Text domain the translation is for. The slug of a theme/plugin or
>  *                                'default' for core translations.
>  *         @type string $version  The version of a theme, plugin, or core.
>  *     }
>  * }
>  */
> do_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', $this, $options['hook_extra'] );
> ```

This below is just the example from codex (it is noted as **untested** there, btw), and I edited it to show a possible instance of all plugin updates:

```
add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'my_upgrate_function',10, 2);

function my_upgrate_function( $upgrader_object, $options ) {


    if ($options['action'] == 'update' && $options['type'] == 'plugin' ) {

       foreach($options['packages'] as $each_plugin) {

             // do stuff

       }//end foreach
    }//end if
}//end my_upgrade_function()
```

Comment: This answer is correct! thank you!! :)

Here is tested code.
https://gist.github.com/ve3/596bbd26b3664f4a006620d06b52f07c

Comment: @vee this gist is no longer available, can you share your solution?

Comment: @RainMan Sorry, I don't have that code anymore but I'm sure that this answer by **hwl** work.